# jquery sort with append reloading a page

Tags: jquery, sorting, append, reload

I have quite easy code that is working proper on other my site... I have span with a text. To this span I bind onclick event. If someone clicks it the table under a span will be sorted. But if I click on it site reloads and on the new page I could see only first image from the table (with FF, on Chrome I can see all images, but ONLY images).

Reload is made on append. I don't have any idea how to fix, especially if I have the same code working proper on other site...

```
<span id="tableSort">Sort</span>
```

and short JS code:

```
jQuery(function(){

    var sortOrder = '';
    function tableSort(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var mylist = jQuery('table#pcWide');
            var listitems = mylist.children('tbody').children('tr').get();
            (sortOrder === '') ? sortOrder = 'd': (sortOrder == 'a')? sortOrder = 'd': sortOrder = 'a';
            listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
                    var ca = jQuery(a).attr('id');
                    var compA = ca.substr(1);
                    var cb = jQuery(b).attr('id');
                    var compB = cb.substr(1);
                    if (sortOrder === 'd') {
                            jQuery('#tableSort').removeClass('sl-down').addClass('sl-up');
                            return compB - compA;
                    } else {
                            jQuery('#tableSort').removeClass('sl-up').addClass('sl-down');
                            return compA - compB;
                    }
            });
            jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {mylist.append(itm);});
    }
    jQuery('span#tableSort').click(function(e) {tableSort(e);});
});
```

Comment: try adding a return false at the end of your tableSort function

Comment: Could you provide a working example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wfx3K/3/ here (the same code) works... so maybe do you have any idea what kind of js code could reload page on `mylist.append(itm);` ? I mean other js code, because there is a lot of code, but not much 'onclick' events...

Comment: @jbduzan reload is done after first append is made... so return false is too late...